# No Targets in TargetRegistry

Tags: llvm

I have the following code, which should get the default llvm::Target.

```
auto const targetTriple = llvm::sys::getDefaultTargetTriple();
llvm_module.setTargetTriple(targetTriple);
std::string error;
auto const * target = llvm::TargetRegistry::lookupTarget(targetTriple, error);
if (target == nullptr) {
    auto targets = llvm::TargetRegistry::targets();
    size_t targetCount = 0;
    for (auto const & _ : targets) {
        ++targetCount;
    }       
    ERROR(Unknown, "llvm::TargetRegistry::lookupTarget failed for " + targetTriple + ". llvm::TargetRegistry::targets() contains " + std::to_string(targetCount) + " elements.");
}
```

This code produces this error message:

> llvm::TargetRegistry::lookupTarget failed for i686-pc-windows-msvc.
>   llvm::TargetRegistry::targets() contains 0 elements

Am I missing a step?

Comment: How do you set up your project? Did you link the native target?

Comment: I'm using CMake to build my program if that's what you mean. I'm only static linking LLVMCore and LLVMSupport at the moment, but I don't get any missing symbols. My CMake build script is here: https://github.com/coder0xff/Plange/blob/master/source/plc/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Did you call `llvm::InitializeNativeTarget()` or `llvm::InitializeAllTargets()`?